# Site Embed Facebook Fan Page Feed WITH Fan Comments

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook Fan Page.  I could embed this feed into a site using Facebook's social activity plugin right now and we'd have nothing else to discuss.  HOWEVER, when I do this, it only includes the content the PAGE posts, not the fan-submitted content.  I'd like to have an embeddable stream of my actual page wall, which includes my content and fan-submitted content.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/, the social activity plugin is working as described.  (of note,

> The activity feed displays stories when users like content on your
>   site, when users share content from your site in Facebook or if they
>   comment on a page on your site in the Comments box.
>
> If a user is logged into Facebook, the plugin will be personalized to
>   highlight content from their friends. If the user is logged out, the
>   activity feed will show recommendations from across your site, and
>   give the user the option to log in to Facebook.

To get the functionality you want, you will have write your own plugin.

Comment: I am aware that the Facebook plugin is working as intended.  I am looking for recommendations (paid plugins, free plugins, whatever) to get the solution I need.

Comment: To get the functionality you want, you will have write your own plugin.